# How to solve Titanium Appcelerator Error "Module not found"

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

i am new into Titanium appcelarator IDE and upon running a project after importing, i get the following error. I didn't get any answers from sites and so i am raising here for your help!

```
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=facebook version=5.0.0 platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.paint version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.rkam.swiperefreshlayout version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.inappbilling version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.cameraandroid version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[ERROR] :  Could not find all required Titanium Modules:
[ERROR] :     id: facebook   version: 5.0.0  platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: ti.paint   version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: com.rkam.swiperefreshlayout    version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: ti.inappbilling    version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: com.cameraandroid  version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: notice: `[ERROR] :  Could not find all required Titanium Modules` this is a short tutoriual how to correctly install titanium paint module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL2HLfXbV5A if it still doesn't work, I would look for the missing modules.

Comment: I added extra info to my answer @KarthikKPN

Answer (score 1):

It clearly looks like you need to include modules into your project. Modules can be put in the, well, `modules` folder in your project root.

Some of the modules in your logs are from Appcelerator and available on the Appcelerator website or GitHub. [Ti.Paint](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.paint) for example.

After adding them to the project root and you re-compile the error should go away.

**Update based on the question updated:**

You added the wrong version of the module. Since you're using 5.5.0.GA you need to have a version of the module that supports that. Because architecture of modules has changed on 6.0.0.GA most modules released an update that only works on 6.0 or higher. You can see inside the module manifest file what the `minsdk` is. For Ti.Paint 3.0 it will say `6.0.0.GA`. This means you need to download an older version of that module and check the related manifest to see if it is supported.

Comment: Hi i have already added those mate. Can you please check into my question now! I have attached the project screenshots now which will give you a better view about my error. thanks

Comment: you included the wrong version that is not supported. You need to include a supported version. Probably an older one